# Can we rename video name save in custom Album of Gallery?

Tags: ios, avplayer

I hope you all are doing fantastic

I am currently working on Video Editing App , here there is one feature where i need to rename the save video name

My flow of saving video

- Select multiple image - create video on document dir - create asset and save in my custom album in gallary

I have search a lot but did not getting any specific link or code which explain the feature i needed.

Can anybody have any idea ?

I need help

Answer (score 0):

You can select the video and duplicate it with

**First: Step 1: Create Action Sheet using UIAlertController**

```
func showAttachmentActionSheet(vc: UIViewController) {
    currentVC = vc
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: Constants.actionFileTypeHeading, message: Constants.actionFileTypeDescription, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.camera, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.authorisationStatus(attachmentTypeEnum: .camera, vc: self.currentVC!)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.phoneLibrary, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.authorisationStatus(attachmentTypeEnum: .photoLibrary, vc: self.currentVC!)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.video, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.authorisationStatus(attachmentTypeEnum: .video, vc: self.currentVC!)

    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.file, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.documentPicker()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.cancelBtnTitle, style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**First: Step 2: Check For Authorisation Status**
Go to Info.plist and add theses lines

```
Privacy — Camera Usage Description 
Privacy — Photo Library Usage Description
```

And add with them these description

```
$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your camera
$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your photo.
```

Then add these function

```
func authorisationStatus(attachmentTypeEnum: AttachmentType, vc: UIViewController){
    currentVC = vc
    if attachmentTypeEnum ==  AttachmentType.camera{
        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        switch status{
        case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
            self.openCamera(currentVC)

        case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
                if granted {
                    self.openCamera(self.currentVC)
                }
            }
        //denied - The user has previously denied access.
        //restricted - The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
        case .denied, .restricted:
            self.addAlertForSettings(attachmentTypeEnum)
            return

        default:
            break
        }
    }else if attachmentTypeEnum == AttachmentType.photoLibrary || attachmentTypeEnum == AttachmentType.video{
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status{
        case .authorized:
            if attachmentTypeEnum == AttachmentType.photoLibrary{
                photoLibrary()
            }

            if attachmentTypeEnum == AttachmentType.video{
                videoLibrary()
            }
        case .denied, .restricted:
            self.addAlertForSettings(attachmentTypeEnum)
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status) in
                if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized{
                    // photo library access given
                    self.photoLibrary()
                }
                if attachmentTypeEnum == AttachmentType.video{
                    self.videoLibrary()
                }
            })
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

with this enum

```
enum AttachmentType: String{
   case camera, video, photoLibrary
}
```

**Step 3: access gallery**

```
func photoLibrary(){
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    currentVC?.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

**Last Step: step4 : access files**

```
func documentPicker(){
    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    currentVC?.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

There you go

Comment: Sorry but i did not get your answer's way